# Как можно при билде вытаскивать хэш коммита?

Tags: java, android

Не знаю на сколько правильный вопрос, но нужно сделать, чтоб когда собирается билд както подтягивать информацию о коммите с которого этот билд делается, чтоб потом можно было отследить если появляется баг то в какой версии...

Как можно такое сделать?

Comment: В какой системе контроля версий? Универсального способа, по очевидным причинам, нет.

Comment: и какая система сборки? В общем случае вы получаете хэш от VCS и кладете его в `.properties` файл при сборке. Можно хоть bat-файлом.

Comment: @D-side работаю с `gitlab`

Comment: @Nofate система сборки `gradle`

Comment: Можно просто выполнить `git rev-parse HEAD` и записать значение в нужное место.

Comment: @Nofate да но каждый раз это делать не удобно, поэтому я хотел автоматизировать...

Comment: Так добавьте эту операцию в gradle-скрипт.